# What is the striking speed of a Green Anaconda?

Tags: snake

How fast does a green anaconda strike? The striking speeds of other snakes is readily accessible, but not that I can find for the anaconda.

If you have information for the size and weight of the anaconda, please include this with your answer. Any additional information about their striking is also welcome.

Comment: A herpetologist friend of mine recounted an experience of wading through a stream, and an anaconda reared up and struck him in the chest, and then pulled back. The strike ripped the man's T-shirt completely off. I can't answer your question, but remember that the strike was very fast, and was quite a shock to the man in the stream (although he was unhurt).

Comment: @KarlKjer Thank you for sharing! If I may ask, did the man comment that it felt like being punched?

Comment: Sorry, it was years ago. I vaguely remember that it did feel like being punched, but memories so old are likely unreliable.

Comment: Thanks Karl. I'm also investigating the strength of a snake strike, separately.